# Is there a way to say that a question flagged as duplicate is not a duplicate?

Tags: support

I've seen a few questions that are flagged as duplicates, but the questions they are apparently duplicates of will elicit completely different answers, and it's just really annoying.

Comment: Can you link them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the privilege to do so, you will see a button called 'reopen' that will let you cast your vote to reopen that question.

[image: Vote to reopen example]

If you do not see that button... you do not have the privilege to vote to reopen. It will take 3,000 reputation points. You can still flag the question for moderator attention, or comment, or link to the question in chat to make your case.

Comment: Why do flags get declined, if you want us to raise them in such a case? I flagged a wrongly closed question and got turned down (before I had the rep needed to reopen vote it myself). The question got reopened anyway,  so I wasn't wrong either.

Comment: @dly mistakes happen; apologies

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make sure how it's being handled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

#### [As per our new policy experiment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/duplicate-questions-a-trial?cb=1):

(People viewing in 2017: unless we choose to continue the policy, this doesn't apply after January 2017)

That is a misflag and the question shouldn't be marked as duplicate. If you see that happening, leave a comment saying that it shouldn't be marked as duplicate and point out that answer doesn't apply. I think that you can put a moderator flag explaining the situation and ask the close votes to be cleared, but a mod clarifying if that's OK would be better.

#### Normally:

That's OK. Asker should put a bounty on the other question saying that the answers doesn't help with his case.

Comment: Oh, right, forgot to state that you can vote to reopen. If you have enough rep and the question is closed, you can vote to reopen as badp said.